# How to avoid dialogs going semi-transparent?

Tags: google-chrome, word-online, microsoft-365

If I double-click a word, I get this (untitled) dialog box:

[image]

If I then move the mouse to reach it, it goes semi-transparent:

[image]

How can I avoid dialogs going semi-transparent like this?

This is on latest Windows Chrome.

Comment: It's practical and detailed. If there's any detail you think would help you answer, then please specify it.